# How to a key in java that the value comes froma string

Tags: java, php

I want to set a key in java from the value that is set from a string
sorry i cant explain this to good so i wrote this in php and here
is a example.

```
class Test() {

    public setField($key, $value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
}

$class = new Test()
$class->setField("hello", "hello world");
echo $class->hello;
```

Comment: This might work in PHP but you can't do this in Java. Maybe if you use Reflection? This is 'smelly' though, you shouldn't be doing this. If you want to use OOP learn the design guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map interface gives the requested behavior:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("hello", "hello world");
        System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
    }
}
```

But you generally want to use variables as keys, and then you would need a method for setting and retrieving every variable.

```
public class Test {
    private String hello;

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello; 
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }
}
public class StackOverflow {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setHello("Hello world");
    System.out.println(test.getHello());
  }
}
```

Or you could make the variable public:

```
   public class Test {
        public String hello;
    }
    public class StackOverflow {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.hello = "Hello world";
        System.out.println(test.hello);
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks i got it working with hashmaps, do those make the code any slower?

Comment: Yes, it's slower than variables. If you can solve the problem with variables you should use variables.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have in-built dynamic variables like PHP. The simplest way to achieve the same functionality this is be to use a `Map`

```
public class Test {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void setField(String key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getField(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

and

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setField("hello", "hello world");
System.out.println(test.getField("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it manually in Java. Something along the lines of:

```
class Test(){
    private HashMap<Object, Object> inner_objects;

    public void setField(Object key, Object value) {
        this.inner_objects.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object getField(Object key){
        return this.inner_objects.get(key);
    }
}
```

Of course this example could be improved in several ways, but it is just to give you the general idea.

But since there is no operator overloading, you can't make `->` work as `getField`, so you will need to call `getField(key)` everytime.